# cadvisor - how to reduce the number of logs

Tags: cadvisor

We enjoy 'cadvisor' for monitoring.

How can I increase the logging level so that much less data is logged?

I read about the '-v=0' command parameter but cannot find further documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging for cAdvisor is taken from glog.  If you follow the comments back through a few other repos you get here eventually: https://github.com/google/glog/tree/master#id11

The important part for you is this:

> The numbers of severity levels `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, and `FATAL` are `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`, respectively.

so using the `-v` flag set accordingly to clean up your log files

Comment: Well, considering the default is 0, I doubt that's the issue, but we will see.

Comment: If default is zero then changing it to 1, 2, or 3 should reduce the number of things being logged.  If I'm reading the question right they want less logging, which usually means ditching info and possibly warning logs.  i.e. setting `-v=2`

Comment: Correct, which is why I changed `--v=0` to `--v=1` in my answer, but there is no way to decrease number, only severity report.

Comment: Which I suppose would inherently decrease number, but you understand my meaning.

Comment: Link in post is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```sh
--log_dir="" #: If non-empty, write log files in this directory
--logtostderr=false #: log to standard error instead of files
--alsologtostderr=false #: log to standard error as well as files
--stderrthreshold=0 #: logs at or above this threshold go to stderr
--v=1 #: log level for V logs
--vmodule= #: comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```

but according to the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/pull/1568) there is currently no way to do so.

Comment: The `--v=1` should increase the threshold required to send an error